# IBM MQ with Mule 4

Tags: ibm-mq, mulesoft, mule4

In our project, we consume a message from IBM MQ (ack-Manual) and after processing we publish the message to other IBM MQ ( either target queue/DL Q - if any errors)
Now, we need to reprocess the messages in DLQ and make sure these messages dont go in infinite loop.
Also, I need to filter the messages (while reading from DLQ) making sure these are not reprocessed messages..
I tried using selector 'attributes.headers.redelivery=false' - but I'm getting Selector Expression error.
Can anyone suggest me how to filter and process the messages in DLQ only once..

Comment: May I know how you are trying to reprocess (is it manual)? you said it will go to DLQ for any errors. In what error scenarios it is going to DLQ?  So before reprocessing the messages from DLQ you need to make sure that the error won't occur again. Otherwise what is the point of having DLQ.

Comment: Both Data Errors and Technical Errors messages would be sent to DLQ.
Technically errored out messages - We are trying to reprocess in a different application.
This application would be listening to DLQ and here we need to filter it

Comment: For any technical errors, when your other application picks the messages from DLQ and reprocesses it picks all the messages from the DLQ and reprocesses them. If there are still any technical errors then only it will put it back to the DLQ otherwise the messages will get processed. In this case, why do you want to have a filter? Maybe I am not understanding your question.